# AWS CodeCommit Eclipse Git Clone Push

Tags: eclipse, git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am unable to clone a repo via HTTPS using Eclipse Git plugin.
And the error is a list of error what the error could be.

But I have Googled it though and it seams that JGit is not working well with AWS CodeCommit.

And I am unable to implement any solution to resolve the occurring problem.

I was able to clone the repo via the basic process using AWS CLI and Git on mac OS X.

I won't be able to use SSH because it is a security requirement.

Could anyone tell me a way to be able to use Git GUI within eclipse with AWS CodeCommit.

Answer (score 1):

Good News! There is now a way to use a username and password to access an AWS CodeCommit repository over https! Check out [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/introducing-git-credentials-a-simple-way-to-connect-to-aws-codecommit-repositories-using-a-static-user-name-and-password/) blog post.